# Erlang server connecting with ports to send and receive a Json file to a Java application

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

I have tried to implement a server with Erlang to my Java application.
Seems that my server is working, but still full of bugs and dead points. 
I need to receive a JSON file parsed by the Java application into a map and send it back to all clients, including the one that uploaded the file.
Meanwhile, I need to keep track who made the request and which part of the message was sent, in case of any problems the client should be restarted from this point, not from the beginning. Unless the client leaves the application, then it should restart.

My three pieces of code will be below:

### The app.erl

```
-module(erlServer_app).

-behaviour(application).

%% Application callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Application callbacks
%%%===================================================================

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    erlServer_sup:start_link().


stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

### The supervisor.erl:

```
-module(erlServer_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

%% API
-export([start_link/0]).

%% Supervisor callbacks
-export([init/1, start_socket/0, terminate_socket/0, empty_listeners/0]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Starts the supervisor
%%
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Supervisor callbacks
%%%===================================================================

init([]) -> % restart strategy 'one_for_one': if one goes down only that one is restarted
  io:format("starting...~n"),
  spawn_link(fun() -> empty_listeners() end),
  {ok,
    {{one_for_one, 5, 30}, % The flag - 5 restart within 30 seconds
      [{erlServer_server, {erlServer_server, init, []}, permanent, 1000, worker, [erlServer_server]}]}}.


%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

start_socket() ->
  supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).

terminate_socket() ->
  supervisor:delete_child(?MODULE, []).

empty_listeners() ->
  [start_socket() || _ <- lists:seq(1,20)],
  ok.
```

### The server.erl:(I have a lot of debugging io:format.)

```
-module(erlServer_server).

%% API
-export([init/0, start_server/0]).

%% Defining the port used.
-define(PORT, 8080).

%%%===================================================================
%%% API
%%%===================================================================

init() ->
  start_server().

%%%===================================================================
%%% Server callbacks
%%%===================================================================

start_server() ->
  io:format("Server started.~n"),
  Pid = spawn_link(fun() ->
    {ok, ServerSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(?PORT, [binary, {packet, 0}, 
      {reuseaddr, true}, {active, true}]),
    io:format("Baba~p", [ServerSocket]),
    server_loop(ServerSocket) end),
  {ok, Pid}.

server_loop(ServerSocket) ->
  io:format("Oba~p", [ServerSocket]),
  {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ServerSocket),
  Pid1 = spawn(fun() -> client() end),
  inet:setopts(Socket, [{packet, 0}, binary, 
    {nodelay, true}, {active, true}]),
  gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid1), 
  server_loop(ServerSocket).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

client() ->
  io:format("Starting client. Enter \'quit\' to exit.~n"),
  Client = self(),
  {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost", ?PORT, [{active, false}, {packet, 2}]),
  display_prompt(Client),
  client_loop(Client, Sock).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Client callbacks
%%%===================================================================

send(Sock, Packet) ->
  {ok, Sock, Packet} = gen_tcp:send(Sock, Packet),
  io:format("Sent ~n").

recv(Packet) ->
  {recv, ok, Packet} = gen_tcp:recv(Packet),
  io:format("Received ~n").

display_prompt(Client) ->
  spawn(fun () ->
    Packet = io:get_line("> "),
    Client ! {entered, Packet}
        end),
  Client ! {requested},
  ok.


client_loop(Client, Sock) ->
  receive
    {entered, "quit\n"} ->
      gen_tcp:close(Sock);
    {entered, Packet}        ->
      % When a packet is entered we receive it,
      recv(Packet),
      display_prompt(Client),
      client_loop(Client, Sock);
    {requested, Packet}        ->
      % When a packet is requested we send it,
      send(Sock, Packet),
      display_prompt(Client),
      client_loop(Client, Sock);
    {error, timeout} ->
      io:format("Send timeout, closing!~n", []),
      Client ! {self(),{error_sending, timeout}},
      gen_tcp:close(Sock);
    {error, OtherSendError} ->
      io:format("Some other error on socket (~p), closing", [OtherSendError]),
      Client ! {self(),{error_sending, OtherSendError}},
      gen_tcp:close(Sock)
  end.
```

This is the first server I'm doing and I got lost probably in the middle. When I run it seems to be working, but hanging. Can someone help me? My localhost never loads anything it keeps loading forever.

How can my java app receive it from the same port?

I MUST use Erlang and I MUST use ports to connect to the java application.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You already got your connection to the client when you did `{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept`. *This* is the socket you need to pass to the client. So `client/0` should be `client/1` and it should accept the connected socket. You do not need to call `gen_tcp:connect ` from this code unless your server is calling *another* server. Erlang is much more simple than Java. There are not objecty things happening in the background in global state. If you don't pass a socket to a function, then that socket is not visible to that function.

Comment: @zxq9 Thanks for your answer. But in the client/1 when you say that I need to accept the connected socket how can I do that, I thought that was the gen_tcp:connect function? Also, when I run the code it never goes to this step. The last printed stage is the first io in server_loop.

Comment: Yes, you *already* accepted a connection from a client. I'll write an example in a bit. I think there is a socket handling example in the Erlang docs for gen_tcp you might want to look at also. http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html

Comment: OK, I wrote an annotated and stripped-down example of a socket service for you (and so I can refer to it in the future because this comes up quite a lot). That gets you to the point of handling sockets -- the next hurdle will be interpreting whatever you receive over that socket. I have not used the Java ports utilities myself, but I *have* use BERT quite a bit, and it works like a charm if you need to speak somewhat natively between a Java (or any other) program and an Erlang one. Drop by [Erlang/OTP chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp) if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rework this just a little...

First up: **Naming**

We don't use camelCase in Erlang. It is confusing because capitalized variable names and lower-case (or single-quoted) atoms *mean* different things. Also, module names *must* be the same as file names which causes problems on case-insensitive filesystems.

Also, we *really* want a better name than "server". Server can mean a lot of things in a system like this, and while the system overall may be a service written in Erlang, it doesn't necessarily mean that we can call everything inside a "server" without getting super ambiguous! That's confusing. I'm going to namespace your project as "ES" for now. So you'll have `es_app` and `es_sup` and so on. This will come in handy later when we want to start defining new modules, maybe some of them called "server" without having to write "server_server" all over the place.

Second: **Input Data**

Generally speaking, we would like to pass arguments to functions instead of burying literals (or worse, macro rewrites) inside of code. If we are going to have magic numbers and constants let's do our best to put them into a configuration file so that we can [access them in a programmatic way](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_env-2), or *even better*, let's use them in the initial startup calls as arguments to subordinate processes so that we can rework the behavior of the system (once written) only by messing around with the startup calling functions in the main application module.

```
-module(es).
-behaviour(application).

-export([listen/1, ignore/0]).
-export([start/0, start/1]).
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

listen(PortNum) ->
    es_client_man:listen(PortNum).

ignore() ->
    es_client_man:ignore().

start() ->
    ok = application:ensure_started(sasl),
    ok = application:start(?MODULE),
    io:format("Starting es...").


start(Port) ->
    ok = start(),
    ok = es_client_man:listen(Port),
    io:format("Startup complete, listening on ~w~n", [Port]).

start(normal, _Args) ->
    es_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

I added a start/1 function above as well as a start/0, a listen/1 and an ignore/0 that you'll see again later in es_client_man. These are mostly convenience wrappers around things you could call more explicitly, but probably won't want to type all the time.

This application module kicks things off by having an application master start the project for us (by calling `application:start/1`) and *then* the next line calls erl_server_server to tell it to start listening. In early development I find this approach much more useful than burying autostarts to every component all over the place, and later on it gives us a *very* simple way to write an external interface that can turn various components on and off.

Ah, also... we're going to start this as a for-real Erlang application, so we'll need an app file in `ebin/` (or if you're using erlang.mk or something similar an app.src file in `src/`):

ebin/es.app looks like this:

```
{application,es,
             [{description,"An Erlang Server example project"},
              {vsn,"0.1.0"},
              {applications,[stdlib,kernel,sasl]},
              {modules,[es,
                        es_sup,
                          es_clients,
                            es_client_sup,
                              es_client,
                            es_client_man]},
              {mod,{es,[]}}]}.
```

The list under `modules` reflects the layout of the supervision tree, actually, as you will see below.

The start/2 function above now asserts that we will only start in `normal` mode (which may or may not be appropriate), and disregards startup args (which also may or may not be appropriate).

Third: [**The Supervision *Tree***](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html)

```
-module(es_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 1, 60},
    Clients   = {es_clients,
                 {es_clients, start_link, []},
                 permanent,
                 5000,
                 supervisor,
                 [es_clients]},
    Children  = [Clients],
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

And then...

```
-module(es_clients).
-behavior(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, none).

init(none) ->
    RestartStrategy = {rest_for_one, 1, 60},
    ClientSup = {es_client_sup,
                 {es_client_sup, start_link, []},
                 permanent,
                 5000,
                 supervisor,
                 [es_client_sup]},
    ClientMan = {es_client_man,
                 {es_client_man, start_link, []},
                 permanent,
                 5000,
                 worker,
                 [es_client_man]},
    Children  = [ClientSup, ClientMan],
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

Whoa! *What is going on here?!?* Well, the es_sup is a *supervisor*, not a one-off thingy that just spawns other one-off thingies. (Misunderstanding [supervisors](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) is part of your core problem.)

Supervisors are boring. *Supervisors should be boring.* All they really do as a reader of code is what the structure of the supervision tree is inside. What they do for us in terms of OTP structure is extremely important, but they don't require that we write any procedural code, just declare what children it should have. What we are implementing here is called a [service -> worker](https://zxq9.com/archives/1311) structure. So we have the top-level supervisor for your overall application called `es_sup`. Below that we have (for now) a single service component called `es_clients`.

The es_clients process is also a supervisor. The reason for this is to define a clear way for the client connection parts to *not affect* whatever ongoing state may exist in the rest of your system later. *Just* accepting connections from clients is useless -- surely there is some state that matters elsewhere, like long-running connections to some Java node or whatever. That would be a *separate* service component maybe called `es_java_nodes` and that part of the program would begin with its own, separate supervisor. That's why it is called a "supervision tree" instead of a "supervision list".

So back to clients... We will have clients connecting. That is why we call them "clients", because *from the perspective of this Erlang system* the things connecting are clients, and the processes that accept those connections *abstract the clients* so we can treat each connection handler as a client itself -- because that is exactly what it represents. If we connect to upstream services later, we would want to call *those* whatever they are abstracting so that our semantics within the system is sane.

You can then think in terms of "an es_client sent a message to an es_java_node to query [thingy]" instead of trying to keep things straight like "a server_server asked a java_server_client to server_server the service_server" (which is literally how stupid things get if you don't keep your naming principles straight in terms of inner-system perspective).

Blah blah blah...

So, here is the es_client_sup:

```
-module(es_client_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_acceptor/1]).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_acceptor(ListenSocket) ->
    supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [ListenSocket]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, none).

init(none) ->
    RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 1, 60},
    Client    = {es_client,
                 {es_client, start_link, []},
                 temporary,
                 brutal_kill,
                 worker,
                 [es_client]},
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, [Client]}}.
```

Are you picking up a pattern? I wasn't kidding when I said that "supervisors should be boring..." :-) Note that here we are actually passing an argument in *and* we have defined an interface function. That is so we have a logicalish place to call if we need a socket acceptor to start.

Fourth: **The Client Service Itself**

Let's look at the client manager:

```
-module(es_client_man).
-behavior(gen_server).

-export([listen/1, ignore/0]).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         code_change/3, terminate/2]).

-record(s, {port_num = none :: none | inet:port_number(),
            listener = none :: none | gen_tcp:socket()}).

listen(PortNum) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {listen, PortNum}).

ignore() ->
    gen_server:cast(?MODULE, ignore).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, none, []).

init(none) ->
    ok = io:format("Starting.~n"),
    State = #s{},
    {ok, State}.

handle_call({listen, PortNum}, _, State) ->
    {Response, NewState} = do_listen(PortNum, State),
    {reply, Response, NewState};
handle_call(Unexpected, From, State) ->
    ok = io:format("~p Unexpected call from ~tp: ~tp~n", [self(), From, Unexpected]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(ignore, State) ->
    NewState = do_ignore(State),
    {noreply, NewState};
handle_cast(Unexpected, State) ->
    ok = io:format("~p Unexpected cast: ~tp~n", [self(), Unexpected]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(Unexpected, State) ->
    ok = io:format("~p Unexpected info: ~tp~n", [self(), Unexpected]),
    {noreply, State}.

code_change(_, State, _) ->
    {ok, State}.

terminate(_, _) ->
    ok.

do_listen(PortNum, State = #s{port_num = none}) ->
    SocketOptions =
        [{active,    once},
         {mode,      binary},
         {keepalive, true},
         {reuseaddr, true}],
    {ok, Listener} = gen_tcp:listen(PortNum, SocketOptions),
    {ok, _} = es_client:start(Listener),
    {ok, State#s{port_num = PortNum, listener = Listener}};
do_listen(_, State = #s{port_num = PortNum}) ->
    ok = io:format("~p Already listening on ~p~n", [self(), PortNum]),
    {{error, {listening, PortNum}}, State}.

do_ignore(State = #s{listener = none}) ->
    State;
do_ignore(State = #s{listener = Listener}) ->
    ok = gen_tcp:close(Listener),
    State#s{listener = none}.
```

Hmmm, what is all that about? The basic idea here is that we have a service supervisor over the whole concept of clients (es_clients, as discussed above), and then we have the simple_one_for_one to handle whatever clients happen to be alive just now (es_client_sup), and here we have the management interface to the subsystem. All this manager does is keep track of what port we are listening on, and *owns the socket* that we are listening to if one is open at the moment. Note that this can be easily rewritten to allow any arbitrary number of ports to be listened to simultaneously, or track all living clients, or whatever. There really is no limit to what you might want to do.

So how do we start clients that can accept connections? By telling them to spawn and listen to the listen socket *that we pass in as an argument*. Go take another look at `es_client_sup` above. We are passing in an empty list as its first argument. What will happen when we call its start_link function is that whatever *else* we pass in as a list will get added to the list of arguments overall. In this case we will pass in the listen socket and so it will be started with the argument `[ListenSocket]`.

Whenever a client listener accepts a connection, its next step will be to *spawn its successor, handing it the original `ListenSocket` argument*. Ah, the miracle of life.

```
-module(es_client).

-export([start/1]).
-export([start_link/1, init/2]).
-export([system_continue/3, system_terminate/4,
         system_get_state/1, system_replace_state/2]).

-record(s, {socket = none :: none | gen_tcp:socket()}).

start(ListenSocket) ->
    es_client_sup:start_acceptor(ListenSocket).

start_link(ListenSocket) ->
    proc_lib:start_link(?MODULE, init, [self(), ListenSocket]).

init(Parent, ListenSocket) ->
    ok = io:format("~p Listening.~n", [self()]),
    Debug = sys:debug_options([]),
    ok = proc_lib:init_ack(Parent, {ok, self()}),
    listen(Parent, Debug, ListenSocket).

listen(Parent, Debug, ListenSocket) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            {ok, _} = start(ListenSocket),
            {ok, Peer} = inet:peername(Socket),
            ok = io:format("~p Connection accepted from: ~p~n", [self(), Peer]),
            State = #s{socket = Socket},
            loop(Parent, Debug, State);
        {error, closed} ->
            ok = io:format("~p Retiring: Listen socket closed.~n", [self()]),
            exit(normal)
     end.

loop(Parent, Debug, State = #s{socket = Socket}) ->
    ok = inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, <<"bye\r\n">>} ->
            ok = io:format("~p Client saying goodbye. Bye!~n", [self()]),
            ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "Bye!\r\n"),
            ok = gen_tcp:shutdown(Socket, read_write),
            exit(normal);
        {tcp, Socket, Message} ->
            ok = io:format("~p received: ~tp~n", [self(), Message]),
            ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, ["You sent: ", Message]),
            loop(Parent, Debug, State);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            ok = io:format("~p Socket closed, retiring.~n", [self()]),
            exit(normal);
        {system, From, Request} ->
            sys:handle_system_msg(Request, From, Parent, ?MODULE, Debug, State);
        Unexpected ->
            ok = io:format("~p Unexpected message: ~tp", [self(), Unexpected]),
            loop(Parent, Debug, State)
    end.

system_continue(Parent, Debug, State) ->
    loop(Parent, Debug, State).

system_terminate(Reason, _Parent, _Debug, _State) ->
    exit(Reason).

system_get_state(Misc) -> {ok, Misc}.

system_replace_state(StateFun, Misc) ->
    {ok, StateFun(Misc), Misc}.
```

Note that above we have written a *Pure Erlang process* that integrates with OTP the way a gen_server would, but has a bit more straightforward loop that handles only the socket. This means we do not have the gen_server call/cast mechanics (and may need to implement those ourselves, but usually asynch-only is a better approach for socket handling). This is [started through the proc_lib module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html) which is designed specifically to bootstrap OTP-compliant processes of any arbitrary type.

If you are going to use supervisors then *you really want to go all the way and use OTP properly*.

So what we have above right now is a *very* basic Telnet echo service. Instead of writing a magical client process inside the server module to tie your brain in knots (Erlangers don't like their brains tied in knots), you can start this, tell it to listen to some port, and telnet to it yourself and see the results.

I added some scripts to automate launching things, but basically the hinge on the `code` and `make` modules. Your project is laid out like

```
es/
   Emakefile
   ebin/es.app
   src/*.erl
```

The contents of the Emakefile will make things easier for us. In this case it is just one line:

`enter code here`{"src/*",  [debug_info, {i, "include/"}, {outdir, "ebin/"}]}.

In the main `es/` directory if we enter an erl shell we can now do...

```
1> code:add_patha("ebin").
true
2> make:all().
up_to_date
3> es:start().
```

And you'll see a bunch of SASL start reports scrolling up the screen.

From there let's do `es:listen(5555)`:

```
4> es:listen(5555).
<0.94.0> Listening.
ok
```

Cool! So it seems like things are working. Let's try to telnet to ourselves:

```
ceverett@changa:~/vcs/es$ telnet localhost 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello es thingy
You sent: Hello es thingy
Yay! It works!
You sent: Yay! It works!
bye
Bye!
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What does that look like on the other side?

```
<0.96.0> Listening.
<0.94.0> Connection accepted from: {{127,0,0,1},60775}
<0.94.0> received: <<"Hello es thingy\r\n">>
<0.94.0> received: <<"Yay! It works!\r\n">>
<0.94.0> Client saying goodbye. Bye!
```

Ah, here we see the "Listening." message from the *next* listener `<0.96.0>` that was spawned by the first one `<0.94.0>`.

How about concurrent connections?

```
<0.97.0> Listening.
<0.96.0> Connection accepted from: {{127,0,0,1},60779}
<0.98.0> Listening.
<0.97.0> Connection accepted from: {{127,0,0,1},60780}
<0.97.0> received: <<"Screen 1\r\n">>
<0.96.0> received: <<"Screen 2\r\n">>
<0.97.0> received: <<"I wonder if I could make screen 1 talk to screen 2...\r\n">>
<0.96.0> received: <<"Time to go\r\n">>
<0.96.0> Client saying goodbye. Bye!
<0.97.0> Client saying goodbye. Bye!
```

Oh, neato. A concurrent server!

From here you can tool around and make this basic structure change to do pretty much anything you might imagine.

**DO NOTE** that there is a lot missing from this code. I have stripped it of [edoc](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/chapter.html) notations and [typespecs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) (used by [Dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html), a critically important tool in a large project) -- which is a BAD thing to do for a production system.

For an example of a production-style project that is small enough to wrap your head around (only 3 modules + full docs), refer to [zuuid](https://github.com/zxq9/zuuid). It was written specifically to serve as a code example, though it happens to be a full-featured UUID generator.

Forgive the hugeness of this answer to your (much shorter) question. This comes up from time to time and I wanted to write a full example of a cut-down network socket service to which I can refer people in the future, and just happened to get the hankering to do so when I read your question. :-) Hopefully the SO nazis will forgive this grievous infraction.